# Get cell width from subclass method

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, width, subclass

I have subclassed cell for UITableView, but struggling to get dynamic width of the cell.descriptionLabel (UILabel)

In my viewController I have imported my subclass for UITableViewCell:

ViewController.m

```
#Import "CustomCell.h"
...

NSInteger widthOfCell = SCREEN_WIDTH - 45; // pass to subclass 
NSLog(@"widthOfCell: %li", (long)widthOfCell); 

...

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

cell.cellWidth = &(widthOfCell);
NSLog(@"cell.cellWidth: %li", (long)cell.cellWidth);
```

And in subclass method CustomCell.h

```
#Import "ViewController"
...
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger *cellWidth;
```

CustomCell.m

```
@synthesize cellWidth = _cellWidth;
...
 if (self) {

    NSLog(@"cell width: %li", (long)_cellWidth);

    self.descriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, (long)_cellWidth, 45)]; 
...
```

In the viewController I can't pass NSInteger without &() as xCode suggest to do.

widthOfCell should return on iPhone 6 after deduction 45 = 330 and NSLog confirms that. But when I try to assign it to cell.cellWidth to pass it to the subclass, it gives this number:
140249523433280

From Subclass NSLog, the value is 0

cell.cellWidth: 140249523433280

cell width: 0

How can I pass the value to subclass, so the width can be dynamic?

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

1. you have not register the Custom cell for tableview , so when you dequeue , you get nil and your Custom Cell is init with the UITableViewCellStyleDefault, it is already inited.
2. if you want to implement a Dynamic Cell just make the cell itself. and adjust the content in the Cell using Auto Layout or CGMake

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have figured out! It is quite simple, not sure why I haven't think of it before!

In my ViewController.m, when initialising CELL for row, I imported the descriptionLabel from subclass and set the width in this method, where widthOfCell is an integer of screen width minus offset I needed.

```
 [cell.descriptionLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, widthOfCell, 45)];
```

Thanks again for making me think differently!
a.